# Center an input using Flexbox in Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I was trying to create a Netflix Landing Page clone using HTML and Tailwind CSS. I wanted to create an input and button in hero section which I tried to center them using flex box, flex-col, justify-center and items-center in parent div.

The problem is that only the button gets centred while the input element remains same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Netflix India</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
  
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body class="font-['Poppins']">
  <header class="relative bg-[url('assets/images/bg.jpg')] h-[70vh] bg-no-repeat bg-center">
    <nav class="flex align-middle justify-between pt-5 px-5">
      <span class="z-20">
        <img class="w-32" src="assets/images/logo.svg" alt="">
        </span>
      <div class="z-20">
        <button class="text-white text-sm rounded border border-gray-500 border-solid py-1.5 px-3">
         English
          </button>
        <button class="text-white bg-[#e50914] py-1.5 text-sm px-3 rounded">Sign In</button>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="absolute top-0 left-0 right-0 h-[70vh] w-full opacity-60 bg-black">
      
    </div>
    <div class="h-[60%] w-[100%] flex flex-col text-center justify-center text-white px-8">
      <span class="z-20 text-[28px] font-bold mb-5">
        Unlimited movies, TV shows and more
      </span>
      <span class="z-20 text-lg mb-5">
        Watch anywhere. Cancel anytime.
      </span>
      <span class="z-20 text-md">
        Ready to watch? Enter your email to create or restart your membership.
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full text-white flex flex-col justify-center align-middle">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="w-[70%]">
      <button>Get Started ></button>
    </div>
  </header>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me get input element to center

Comment: when a flex is in the direction of column, justify-center aligns vertically not horizontally, add the class items-center and you should be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a parent element with 100% width:

```
<div class="relative z-[2] flex w-full flex-col justify-center align-middle text-white">
  <div class="flex w-full flex-col items-center justify-center">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="w-[70%]" />
    <button class="text-white">Get Started ></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here you go, this should work for you:

```
<header class="relative h-[70vh] bg-[url('assets/images/bg.jpg')] bg-center bg-no-repeat">
  <nav class="flex justify-between px-5 pt-5 align-middle">
    <span class="z-20">
      <img class="w-32" src="assets/images/logo.svg" alt="" />
    </span>
    <div class="z-20">
      <button class="rounded border border-solid border-gray-500 px-3 py-1.5 text-sm text-white">
        English
      </button>
      <button class="rounded bg-[#e50914] px-3 py-1.5 text-sm text-white">
        Sign In
      </button>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="absolute left-0 right-0 top-0 z-[1] h-[70vh] w-full bg-black opacity-60"></div>
  <div class="relative z-[2] flex h-[60%] w-[100%] flex-col justify-center px-8 text-center text-white">
    <span class="z-20 mb-5 text-[28px] font-bold">
      {" "}
      Unlimited movies, TV shows and more{" "}
    </span>
    <span class="z-20 mb-5 text-lg"> Watch anywhere. Cancel anytime. </span>
    <span class="text-md z-20">
      {" "}
      Ready to watch? Enter your email to create or restart your membership.{" "}
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="relative z-[2] flex w-full flex-col justify-center align-middle text-white">
    <div class="flex w-full flex-col items-center justify-center">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="w-[70%]" />
      <button class="text-white">Get Started ></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: ✌ have fun learning!